# insert characters in a string if the previous four characters are a number

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, string

I have a string in which every time there is a number there is no space. I would like to create it and add a comma.

For example, the following:

```
2013 Presidential2008 Presidential2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Runoff2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Rerun
```

would be transformed in :

```
2013 Presidential, 2008 Presidential, 2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Runoff2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Rerun
```

Until now I have :

```
for char in s:
...     if char.isalpha():
            ???
```

I also tried with Javascript:

```
function isNumber(c) {
    return (i >= '0' && i <= '9');
}
for (var x = 0; x < text.length; x++)
{
    var c = text.charAt(x);
    if isNumber(i){
        // add a ", " before and move to the next char which is a letter
        text[:x] + ', ' + text[x:]
    }   
}
```

But it returns: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: _"But it returns: ..."_ - Because this is not JavaScript. And even after fixing the syntax it would not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into `string.prototype.replace` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)).

```js
let input = '2013 Presidential2008 Presidential2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Runoff2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Rerun'

//           replace:   (non-digit)(digit)
let output = input.replace(/([^\d])(\d)/g, '$1, $2');
//                           with:   non-digit, digit

console.log(output);
```

If your input will have digits that already follow a space, then you can make sure not to add commas to them by modifying the regex slightly:

```js
let input = '1 noSpace2 space 3';

//  replace:   (non-digit nor space)(digit)
let output = input.replace(/([^\d ])(\d)/g, '$1, $2');
//                           with:   non-digit, digit

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm new to javascript but I guess that `[^\d]` takes non-digit *numbers* and not *digit*?

Comment: This is standard regex, and not specific to JS. `\d` matches digits, `[^x]`, matches not-x, and together, `[^\d]` matches non-digits.

Answer (score 3):

Using regex on Python:

```
import re

text = '2013 Presidential2008 Presidential2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Runoff2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Rerun'

pat = re.compile(r'([^\d\s])(\d+)')
pat.sub(r'\1, \2', text)
```

Output:

```
'2013 Presidential, 2008 Presidential, 2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Runoff, 2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian Rerun'
```

Sample: https://regex101.com/r/tDdfsc/1

Comment: Or: ``re.sub('(?<=.)(\d{4})', r', \1', text)``

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, what would `(?<=.)` and `\1` stands for?

Comment: r.ook, if `[^\d]` matches non-digits, what does `[^\d\s]` matches? And what about  `(\d+)`?

Comment: `(?<=.)` is a *Positive Lookbehind* for any character except line terminator (denoted by `.`).  The `\1` is the respective captured group #1.

Comment: `[^\d\s]` looks for non-digit AND non-space, so that any preceding alphabets/symbols is captured.  `[a-zA-Z]` is also a possible option if you are only looking for alphabets.  `(\d+)` captures a continuous string of digits until a non-digit is present.  Check the sampled link in my answer for more details.